# splitting long text file in python

Tags: parsing, text

I have a long text file of messages. I would like to split each message to one row with the fields each going to a separate column. The messages are delimited with ';'. Each of the fields is labeled ('Sent:', 'From:' etc) except for the body. I've been struggling with this for days trying a longer script using split but I'm not having much success. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The text file has the following structure:

```
;Message 1 of 948 
Sent:  08/31/2022 at 06:42 PM  
From:  Mary Smith  
To:  John Smith (First Viewed: 09/06/2022 at 09:48 AM)
Subject:  Test  

Hello this is a test message. Sometimes
There are returns in the message.  

;Message 2 of 948 
Sent:  09/24/2022 at 10:23 AM  
From:  John Smith  
To:  Mary Smith (First Viewed: 09/24/2022 at 10:10 PM)  
Subject:  Message 2  

Hi This is a test message 

;Message 3 of 948 
Sent:  09/24/2022 at 10:10 PM  
From:  John Smith  
To:  Mary Smith (First Viewed: 09/25/2022 at 10:46 AM)  
Subject:  Re: Test  

This is a reply to the test message
```

I have tried using both regex and split. I can't get either to work. I have managed to put everything in one column with the below but each message occupies multiple rows.

```
import csv

with open("emails.txt") as txt, open('theoutput.csv', 'a') as csvfile:
  writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')

  writer.writerow(('ID', 'Reporttext'))
  id = 1
  for line in txt:
    words = line.strip().split(";")

    for word in words:
        writer.writerow((id, word.strip()))
        id += 1
```

Can you help? Thank you

Comment: You iterate over your input text line by line.  Maybe `txt.read()` the whole thing, then split by message then process each message.  Use functions?  Does all messages have the same headers in the same order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to read your in one go, strip the first line and then use `^;Message.*\n` as the separate.  Split header and body and extract the values from the header (this assumes the same set of headers in the same order; if not use a DictWriter instead).

I sprinkled some `strip()` in there to remove what appear to be extra newlines.  It's not clear if you want those or not.

No csv header is written the output file but should be easy to extract from the the first header.  If email header differ between lines then you have to process all rows before figuring out what the csv header must be:

```
import re
import csv

with open("emails.txt") as txt, open('theoutput.csv', 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
    csvfile = csv.writer(csvfile)
    # read content and remove first line
    data = txt.read().split('\n', 2)[2]
    for msg in re.split('^;Message.*\n', data, flags=re.M):
        header, body = re.split('\n\n', msg, 1, re.M)
        header_values = [l.split(':', 1)[1].strip() for l in header.split('\n')]
        csvfile.writerow(header_values + [body.strip()])
```

and resulting output:

```
Mary Smith,John Smith (First Viewed: 09/06/2022 at 09:48 AM),Test,"Hello this is a test message. Sometimes
There are returns in the message."
09/24/2022 at 10:23 AM,John Smith,Mary Smith (First Viewed: 09/24/2022 at 10:10 PM),Message 2,Hi This is a test message
09/24/2022 at 10:10 PM,John Smith,Mary Smith (First Viewed: 09/25/2022 at 10:46 AM),Re: Test,This is a reply to the test message
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm getting an error in the header, body line so something in my data doesn't match. Trying to figure it out on my own. I'm very new to coding and really appreciate the help.

Comment: I suggest you accept the answer to your question.  If you need help with different input then use `print(msg)` prior that line and include that in a new question.  Feel free to post my code in the new question.